# manipulate json through ajax/jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I created two JSONs in a php file.

1. `$response = array('invalid' => true);`
2. `$response = array('valid' => true);`

Now I create an ajax and try to change the class if input box according to json.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/script/validate_email.php',
    data: {i_emial:val_i_email},
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) { 
            $('#div118').html(data);
            if (response.valid == true) {
            // remove previous class and add another class
            } else {
            // remove previous class and add another class
            }
    }
});
```

But it not working. How to solve?

But result data in #div118 shows : `{"invalid":true}` or `{"valid":true}`

edit: forgot to mention that i use `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: 1) `$response` is an array, not JSON. You are *encoding* the data as JSON later on with `json_encode` (I hope). 2) `response` is not defined in your JavaScript code. I probably want to use `data`. 3) You might have to parse the JSON to a JavaScript object first. *edit:* Yes, you definitely have to do that.

Comment: @burey your data is what is displayed in the div right? so you should be able to access it as JSON.parse(data).valid. DO a console.log(data) and see what it says in chrome. if it says object then you can directly do data.valid, if it displays the full text then you would need to do a JSON parse. but specifying a datatype in the ajax call would reduce the extra JSON.parse

Comment: The fact that the `div` shows e.g. `{"valid":true}` instead `[object Object]` indicates that jQuery does not find the proper content type header and did not parse the response. Something might be wrong there...

Answer (score 1):

`response` is not defined in your code. You also have to parse the response (the JSON) into a JavaScript object, or let jQuery know to do this for you:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    dataType: 'json', // <- let jQuery know which data format to expect
    success: function (data) { // <- you define data here
        if (data.valid) { // <- data, not response; no need to compare
            // remove previous class and add another class
        } else {
            // remove previous class and add another class
        }
    }
});
```

Or even better: jQuery (and other services) can figure out the data format the response is sent, if you [set the appropriate content type header for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267546/218196) in PHP.

Comment: Shouldn't that be datatype:'json'?

Comment: @burey: Well, *"it does not work"* is not really informative. I cannot really help you there. I can only point you to [learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). Set a breakpoint in your success handler and inspect the response. Or try to be more specific. The issue might be that you are using either `invalid` or `valid` as keys. Better would be `valid:true` and `valid:false` I guess.

Comment: The add class does not respond to the if statement

Comment: Ok, then as I said, set a breakpoint, inspect `data` and see whether `data.valid` is what you expect it to be. Basic debugging :)